# SINA News Web Scraping

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

I'm trying to web scrape using RVest: [SINA](http://www.sina.com.cn/mid/search.shtml?range=all&c=news&q=%E6%B1%87%E4%B8%B0%E9%93%B6%E8%A1%8C&from=home&ie=utf-8)

**Question 1:**

I would like to obtain the link for the next page located at the bottom as

[image: Next Page Button]

When I inspect using Chrome:

[image: Inspect]

```
rm(list=ls())
library(rvest)

# Search Sina HSBC
hsbc_sina_search = read_html('http://www.sina.com.cn/mid/search.shtml?range=all&c=news&q=%E6%B1%87%E4%B8%B0%E9%93%B6%E8%A1%8C&from=home&ie=utf-8', encoding = 'UTF-8')

#Next Page
hsbc_sina_search %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//table/tbody/tr/td/div[@class='pagebox']/a[10]")
```

it returns:

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Is there something wrong with my xpath?

> "//table/tbody/tr/td/div[@class='pagebox']/a[10]"

What I'm trying to achieve is to get to the next page. How should I go about doing so if rvest cannot do this?

**Question 2:**

For the same [webpage](http://www.sina.com.cn/mid/search.shtml?range=all&c=news&q=%E6%B1%87%E4%B8%B0%E9%93%B6%E8%A1%8C&from=home&ie=utf-8), I would like to obtain the hrefs of the links
[image: HREF]

[image: Link Inspect]

```
# Link In
hsbc_sina_search %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class='box-result clearfix' and @data-sudaclick = 'blk_result_index_9']/div/h2/a")
```

I'm not getting any results as well

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think you have to "click" the page for the html to even load. PhantomJS, among others, does that, I think.

Comment: To get the results you can riff off of this URL I ripped from the XHR request list and slightly modified `jsonlite::fromJSON("http://api.search.sina.com.cn/?c=news&q=%E6%B1%87%E4%B8%B0%E9%93%B6%E8%A1%8C&stime=2016-03-10&etime=2017-03-12&sort=rel&highlight=-&num=100&ie=utf-8&callback=&_=")`

Comment: The workaround could be to parse all numbers in pagination section instead of clicking the button. Then, use pagination numbers as you need.